# Why does Jpa/EclipseLink merge an entity set its id to 0 after adding Descriptor Customizer for entity?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

After I activated EclipseLink Descriptor Customizer for tracking history of changes over entities, merge an entity sets its BigInteger id to 0. When I deactivate Customizer class, everything is ok. What am I doing wrong here?

This is my Customizer class

```
public class HumanResource_EmployeeCustomizer implements DescriptorCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ClassDescriptor cd) throws Exception {
        HistoryPolicy policy = new HistoryPolicy();
        policy.addStartFieldName("START");
        policy.addEndFieldName("END");
        policy.addHistoryTableName("EMPLOYEE", "HUMANRESOURCE_EMPLOYEE_");
        cd.setHistoryPolicy(policy);
    }
}
```

[entity id before commit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exX1B.jpg)

[entity id after commit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvMIG.jpg)